# Vuejs v-html directive in dynamic component

Tags: vue.js

I want to use the `v-html` directive with a dynamic component in Vuejs (3).
But the content from `v-html` don't show up.

```
<component :is="Whatever" v-html="HTMLString"></component>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can pass `HTMLString` as a normal param and then in your custom component you can bind that using `v-html` tag.

Comment: `v-html` uses `innerHTML` - so it can be applied to native HTML tags only.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment. You can pass HTML string in a normal param and then in your custom component you can bind that using v-html tag.

Give a try **:**

```js
Vue.component("Whatever", {
    props: ["str"],
    template: '<div v-html="str"></div>'
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      htmlString: '<h1>Hello</h1>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <component is="Whatever" :str="htmlString">
    </component>
</div>
```